# How to convert time bins in spectrogram to real time?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I have an output of a spectrogram with the shape of (8193, 2110). This means that I have 2110 time frames and 8193 frequency bins. I want to convert time bins to real time. This spectrogram is related to a one day long file, so instead on time frame I need the exact real time like : 12:32:45.

Comment: Depends on sample rate, FFT size, and overlap factor.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the formula for this relationship?

Comment: I’ve put together an answer below,

Answer (score 1):

A single FFT in your spectrogram represents a time window of duration `T = N / Fs`, where `N` = FFT size and `Fs` = sample rate. If you have no overlap between successive FFTs then the `i`’th FFT represents a time window of duration `T`, starting at time `i*T`.

If you have overlap between successive FFTs, e.g. `k = 0.5` (50% overlap), then `i*T` obviously becomes `(1-k)*i*T`.